# send 2 audio streams from one device to 2 separate speakers in parallel by bluetooth

Tags: audio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, audio-streaming, android-bluetooth

I know that is possible to stream one audio in multiple speaker in parallel (dual audio).Also, it's possible to have 2 SPP (Serial port over bluetooth) in parallel.
But is it possible send 2 audio streams from one device to 2 separate speakers in parallel by bluetooth?
I don't care much if there is an application already is doing it(however, it will be great), but if there is any technology limitation.
There is the new feature called Auracast, but I don't think it supports it.
You can have 2 audio streams in a bluetooth device for the left and right headphone. So I think should be possible. Someone knows something about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that is possible have multiple stream in  5.2 bluetooth stack. Ble audio (Auracast) support multiple stream. It's quite new technology, this is the reason why there isn't much information.